# Getting currently active menu title in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, styles

I need to get currently active menu item (menu title like Home, About us, etc..) on each page in wordpress. I am using wordpress codes to display menu & it displayed correctly. Code is shown below,

```
    $menu_name = 'primary';
    if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) )
    {
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
        $menu_list = '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name . '" class="nav navbar-nav" style="width:100%;">';

        foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item )
        {
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $url = $menu_item->url;
            $menu_list .= '<li class="menu-line"><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
        }
        $menu_list .= '</ul>';
    } else {
    $menu_list = '<ul><li>Menu "' . $menu_name . '" not defined.</li></ul>';
    }
    echo $menu_list;
```

But I am not able to identify which menu item is active now.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: ya its work fine for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your code like this and add your css as per your requirement.

```
<?php
 $menu_name = 'primary';
    if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) )
    {
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
        $menu_list = '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name . '" class="nav navbar-nav" style="width:100%;">';

        foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item )
        {
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $url = $menu_item->url;
            $active = '';
            $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";           
            if($url == $actual_link) 
            {
                 $active = 'active';
            }
            else
            {
                $active = '';
            }
            $menu_list .= '<li class="menu-line"><a href="' . $url . '" class="'.$active.'">' . $title . '</a></li>';
        }
        $menu_list .= '</ul>';
    } else {
    $menu_list = '<ul><li>Menu "' . $menu_name . '" not defined.</li></ul>';
    }
    echo $menu_list;
?>
```

CSS as below

```
<style>
.active { border:1px solid #f00;}
</style>
```

It work fine for my code.