# Wordpress Elementor - Button Remain Hover

Tags: wordpress, button, elementor

I have 3 buttons with hover effect on my website header. Clicking on the buttons bring you to a specific page on my website.

How do I make the button remain in hover effect when the button URL matches the address bar URL?

ie.

Address bar : weburl/2

Button 1 : weburl/1

Button 2 : weburl/2 <- I want this button to remain in hover effect

Button 3 : weburl/3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting currently active menu title in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253576/getting-currently-active-menu-title-in-wordpress)

Answer (score -1):

First, add class to all three buttons button1,button2,button3, and go to the specific button url page and edit with elementor of each page and add a custom HTML widget and write hover effect css in the widget using button class.